# Why getting MAX and MIN using GROUP BY takes so much time?

Tags: oracle, performance, group-by, query-optimization, aggregate-functions

I wrote below query and it takes too long time to get the data. So any advice to make it faster?

```
   SELECT to_char(empno) empno
      ,e.basicsl basic_sal
      ,e.govt_cont gov_cont
      ,e.pensnd emp_paid_cont
      ,MAX(to_date(e.pstyymm, 'yyyymm')) MAX
      ,MIN(to_date(e.pstyymm, 'yyyymm')) MIN
      ,e.hsealwn h_alwn
      ,e.elcalwn e_alwn
      ,e.wtralwn wtr_alwn
  FROM pen_ded e
 GROUP BY e.empno
         ,e.basicsl
         ,e.govt_cont
         ,e.pensnd
         ,e.hsealwn
         ,e.elcalwn
         ,e.wtralwn
```

Comment: use parallel hint: `select /*+parallel(e 8)*/ bla bla...`

Comment: how much is _too long time_?

Comment: it depends also on the data , how any count does it have ? what kind of data does it include ? why you didnt use conditions ? are there a pk on the table?

Comment: The question is not unclear, it's just too broad...

Comment: You can improve the full scan time for example using compression. Compress the table and it will be read faster. But compression has a licence to be paid.

Comment: the db is fine when i put max/min sub-query it takes seconds only

Comment: Group by uses sorting(or hashing) algorithms which need memory(and aditional time). Maybe there is not enough pga memory to do the group by and eventually uses the TEMP tablespace which is much slower. Verify the memory.

Comment: /*+parallel(e 8)*/ i added this one and its really works very fast